# Cloud Computing

Tags: cloud

I have created a web based project in Jsp and Servlets which works good on the Apache Tomcat Server. I want to know how can i put it on Amazon using Cloud Technology.

Comment: Cloud technology is a general technology term not an specific protocol. You should refer to any cloud-provider's manual you're seeking.

Answer (score 5):

First, I recommend going through the [Get Started with EC2](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/GettingStartedGuide/) guide to get the perspective of an end user new to cloud computing. This involves using the EC2 web console to control the cloud.  This is a good guide for novice users.

Second, try going through the [Getting Started with the Command Line Tools](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?SettingUp_CommandLine.html) guide. Once you've completed the Setting Up the Tools step you'll want to jump to the [Launching and Using Instances](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?LaunchingAndUsingInstances.html) guide. This uses the EC2 command line interface to control the cloud. This is the guide for advanced users.

Once you've got a VM up and running try deploying Tomcat as usual. This should get your feet wet.

Answer (score 0):

Upload your project's .war in elastic bean stalk and deploy project.

The steps to create a new application in beanstalk are:

1. Create a new application say "test app" in Elastic beanstalk, chose the region which best suits your requirement.
2. Create a new environment in the application "test app", select the application server you like to have i.e, tomcat 6 32/64 or tomcat732/64.
3. upload the .war in the newly created environment.
4. You can provide a custom Cname through which you can access you web application from browser.
5. Finally based on your requirements you can set the healthcheck status time interval, scaling unit

For further help you can also buy any [cloud management software](http://www.netboundary.com/services/cloud-services) to upload and manage your web based application easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a PaaS instead of an IaaS to deploy your application to Amazon. The benefit of this is that you don't need to configure, neither to install Tomcat, MySQL,.. you just enable the services that you would like and just start using them. This is a [guide](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/09/bind-your-java-application-to-your.html) which explains you how to deploy your application to a specific PaaS specialized in java stacks as they support Tomcat, JBoss, Jetty and Glassfish.

You should look for all the alternatives that you could have and just choose what is better depending on your needs.